# Synchronization error in consumer/producer style logger

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging, producer-consumer, condition-variable

I see lots of this sort of questions but none helped me so I post mine.

I made a logger for multi-thread logging.
Only one thread(Created when the very first logger is created.) deals with log messages from many threads and the buffer is synchronized using condition variables. One for `push()` and one for `pop()`.

It seemed working fine but it doesn't work when it comes to too many messages in a short time.

Here's the exception message from xutility.

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
_Pnext was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

And this is my code.

logger.h

```
class ConsoleLogger
{
private:
    static Buffer<std::string, 1000> buffer;
    uint32_t curLine = 0;
    static bool instantiated;
    std::mutex logLock;
    std::string prefix;
    std::ostringstream logStream;

    // creates log thread one very first logger calls constructor
    void createLogThread();
    // keeps logging incoming logs
    static void logThreadFunc();

public:
    ConsoleLogger();
    void setPrefix(const std::string_view& newPrefix);

    template<typename T, typename... Types>
    void log(T log1, Types... logs) {
        {
            std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(logLock);
            noLog = false;

            logStream.clear();
            logStream.str("");
            logStream << prefix << "#" << curLine << "\t" << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\t";
            ++curLine;

            logMessage(log1, logs...);
        }
    }

private:
    void logMessage() {
        logStream << "\n";

        std::string* str = new std::string{ logStream.str() };

        buffer.push(str);
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Types>
    void logMessage(T log1, Types... logs) {
        logStream << log1;
        logMessage(logs...);
    }
};
```

logger.cpp

```
Buffer<std::string, 1000> ConsoleLogger::buffer;

void ConsoleLogger::logThreadFunc() {
    while (true) {
        std::string* log = buffer.pop();
        if (log == nullptr) {
            std::cerr << "log was nullptr" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        std::cout << *log;
        delete log;          <-------------throws exception

    }
}
```

buffer.h

```
template<class T, uint64_t Qsize>
class Buffer
{
private:
    T* arrayPtr[Qsize];
    uint64_t head;
    uint64_t tail;
    static const uint64_t mask = Qsize - 1;

    std::condition_variable condEmpty;
    std::condition_variable condOverflow;
    std::mutex mtx;
public:
    Buffer();

    void push(T* x);
    T* pop();
};

template <class T, uint64_t Qsize>
Buffer<T, Qsize>::Buffer() : head(0),
                             tail(0)
{}

template <class T, uint64_t Qsize>
void Buffer<T, Qsize>::push(T* x)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

    condOverflow.wait(lock, [this]() {
        return tail + Qsize > head;
        });

    arrayPtr[head++ & mask] = x;

    lock.unlock();
    condEmpty.notify_one();
}

template <class T, uint64_t Qsize>
T* Buffer<T, Qsize>::pop()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

    condEmpty.wait(lock, [this]() {
        return tail < head;
        });

    T* x = arrayPtr[tail++ & mask];

    lock.unlock();
    condOverflow.notify_one();

    return x;
}
```

I've been trying to fix this for the last couple days but I have no idea why is this happening.
I think it keeps trying to access already deleted memory.
I tested without deleting and it logs the same message it already printed.

Any suggestions or help would be very thankful.

Comment: Doesn't look like you're properly initializing the elements of your `arrayPtr`, so `pop` when nothing is available seems undefined

Comment: If third party library is acceptable, Boost::log is a good option for multi-threaded environment.

Comment: What is `arrayPtr[head++ & mask]` supposed to do?  Are you sure you don't mean `arrayPtr[head++ % Qsize]` instead (and similarly for `arrayPtr[tail++ & mask]` in `Buffer::pop`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explicitly null out the elements of the `arrayPtr`

```
template <class T, uint64_t Qsize>
Buffer<T, Qsize>::Buffer() : head(0),
                             tail(0)
{
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < Qsize; i++)
        arrayPtr[i] = nullptr;
}
```